# MS Excel: I need to consolidate multiple orders placed by the same company

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have thousands of orders with columns A-AC with necessary data pertaining to their orders. (Did they have a discount? What was the total amount they paid? What's the billing name and address, what's the shipping name and address, what was the date they ordered, etc)

I want to eventually create a list from all of these orders in order of highest sales to lowest sales. The issue is that several companies may have ordered 30 different times and either spelled their company names the same when filling out the online order form or used "&" instead of 'and', the list goes on and on.

Is there a way to have excel combine like company names and add the values associated to each order. For example if we had:
McDonalds  $200,000.00
Mc Donalds $    300.00
MCD        $ 20,000.00

Could I ever get it to read: McDonalds $220,300.00?

Any information would be appreciated as the current score is Taylor: 0, Excel: 238.

Thanks,
Taylor

Comment: I'd start with maybe a "find and replace" for "&" to "and" and then maybe some filtering because they should all still start with the same character. But no, excel unfortunately doesn't have AI; You'll need to give it the information to do what it does.

Comment: This is do-able in Excel, but firstly, q question:   do you need to do this as a one-off exercise, or will the data be changing on an on-going basis?

Answer (score 2):

I think just about any software you use would require normalizing the names, you would probably add another table which would have "name provided" and "standard name" and then use a lookup to return the "standard name" for each row.

Once the data has standard names you could use a pivot table to sum and average to your hearts content.

From the sounds of it your data would be much better stored in a database instead of excel.

Comment: Yes, database will most def. be better, there it also will be easier for you to run SQL queries to normalize the names and check whether you have normalised all of them. Definitely through adding standard name field, then running queries to set that field to standard name, if the name field is say mcdonal* or McDonal* etc. In your order form on the web you could use dropdown list for companies that buy frequently.